# How to search unread mail in Outlook with VBScript?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am able to open Outlook, focus it to the inbox folder, and count unread mails with .Unread.

I would like to be able to search unread email for a particular email address in the body of the emails.

I am using Windows 7 with Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) or [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) methods of the Items class. Take a look at the following articles for the sample code and more information about them:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, to find all unread emails in the folder you can use the following search criteria:

```
  [UnRead] = true
```

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the Filtering article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- Finally, you can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

- Body - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
- HTMLBody - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
- Word editor - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to customize the message body.

Comment: Hi Eugene,

Really thanks for your explanation and links. Is there any property that can search body for Hyperlinks. If poossible could you please give me a sample line of code for that..

Thanks