# How to filter unread emails by keyword in subject using VBScript?

Tags: outlook, vbscript, wildcard

I have this code below that allows to define the number of all unread emails in outlook Inbox. How to adjust the code to determine the number of unread emails with the keyword “(STL-1491 v14.0)” in subject using wildcard in VBScript?

```
Function CountUnReadMsgs
Dim myOlApp
Dim myOlNameSpace
Dim objFolder
Dim itms
Dim ItemCount, UnReadItemCount

  'get running outlook application or open outlook
    Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If myOlApp Is Nothing Then
            Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If
  
Set myOlNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = myOlNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set itms = objfolder.Items
ItemCount = itms.Count
'ItemCount is total number of messages

UnReadItemCount = objFolder.UnReadItemCount
CountUnReadMsgs = UnReadItemcount

End Function
```

Comment: The way to do a keyword search in VBS is `If InStr(YourString,"STL-1491 v14.0") > 0 Then...`  I'm not sure what you could use as the string to apply the condition to though

Comment: Iterating over all items is not really a good idea...

Comment: John and Eugene Astafiev, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx) / [FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class to get all items that correspond to your search criteria. For example, a sample code in VB.NET:

```
Dim searchCriteria As String = "[UnRead] = true"
Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing
Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
    
If (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0) Then
   strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
   folderItems = folder.Items
   resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
   While Not IsNothing(resultItem)
       If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
          counter += 1
          mail = resultItem
          strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                          " - Subject: " + mail.Subject)
       End If
       resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
   End While
   If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
      Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
   End If
Else
   Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                                   folder.Name + " folder.")
End If
```

Also you may combine multiple conditions in the single search criteria string using logical AND operations.

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Get unread Outlook e-mail items from the Inbox folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/27/outlook-get-unread-items/)

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Comment: Thanks Eugene Astafiev for your answer and references.

Comment: This question is asking about [tag:VBScript], not [tag:VB.Net].

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages.

Comment: Yes, but the syntax in various versions of VB differs. This is a VBScript question, so those unfamiliar with the family of VB languages will not realise that code like `As StringBuilder` will not work in VBScript. Just because the object model is the same doesn't mean it's implemented exactly the same way.

Comment: Seems you make a habit of posting a VB.Net answer on a [VBA question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767970/692942). Similar topic.

Comment: The sequence of the Outlook object model's methods and properties are the same for both languages. The code can be easily adapted for VBScript. It is not a habit, that is because I don't use VBScript.